# How to solve integral $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(a\cos\phi + b\sin\phi)} \cos\phi\ d\phi$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I'm trying to solve $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(a\cos\phi + b\sin\phi)} \cos\phi\ d\phi$ for a radiation problem in physics. In the special case that $b = 0$, this reduces to a Bessel function of the first kind, but I have no clue where to start for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Idea: $a \cos \phi+b \sin \phi = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cos(\phi-\phi_0)$ and then translate $\phi$. But you'll get a factor $\cos(\phi+\phi_0)$ outside which you would possibly have to develop.

Comment: Bessel: $\displaystyle{\,\mathrm{J}_{1}}$.

Comment: Split the exponential into two exponentials. Series expand the exponentials, most terms will vanish.

Comment: @FelixMarin. Bessel $2 i \pi  J_1(a)$ if $b=0$ I suppose. $b$ seems to be very problematic (at least to me).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(a\cos\phi+b\sin\phi)}\cos\phi \, d\phi
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \left(-i \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right) e^{i(a\cos\phi+b\sin\phi)}\,d\phi \\
&= -i \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(a\cos\phi+b\sin\phi)}\,d\phi 
    & \textrm{Leibniz rule} \\
&= -i \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(\phi-\phi_0)}\,d\phi 
    & \textrm{see comment of H. H. Rugh}  \\
&= -i \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos t}\,d t 
    & \textrm{periodicity of cosine} \\
&= -i \frac{\partial}{\partial a} 2\pi J_0\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right) 
    & \textrm{standard integral} \\
&= \frac{2\pi i a J_1\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
    & J_0'(x)=-J_1(x)
\end{align*}